# Unable to apply jQuery Chosen on <s:select>

Tags: html, jquery, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I am using `<s:select>` (Struts2) drop-down with class `chosen-select` but that doesn't work. The class in generated HTML is like `class="class java.util.HashMap"`.

Whereas if I use HTML `<select>` and same class `chosen-select` which works perfect. What is the problem with Struts 2 drop-down ?

**Struts 2 Dropdown:**

```jsp
<s:select list="products" id="productsList_" listKey="id" listValue="name"
          headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Product" style="width:200px;"
          theme="simple" class="chosen-select" />
```

**HTML Dropdown:**

```html
<select id="productsList_" name = "products" class="chosen-select" ></select>
```

Comment: Problem is that you need to use proper attributes in tags. http://struts.apache.org/docs/select.html.

Comment: @AleksandrM In this *doc* attributes are in the list.

Comment: @RomanC: It is latest doc. *Now* you can use `class` or `cssClass`.

Comment: @AleksandrM Both are parsed?

Comment: @RomanC: You mean evaluated? Don't think so. `class` was producing *hashmap* because of the name -> *class*.

Comment: @AleksandrM What does it mean *evaluated* in the doc?

Comment: @RomanC: Good question. As it seems it is always `false` for everything, which is not true. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are special attributes for CSS in the Struts UI tags. Instead of `class` attribute use `cssClass` and instead of `style` use `cssStyle`. Even if `<s:select>` tag allows dynamic attributes it parses the value for OGNL expression. And if you didn't define a variable with the key `"chosen-select"` in the value stack it might return occasionally a match. In your case it's some `Class` object, which has not any meaning to the code.

The documentation page for [`<s:select>` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/select-tag.html) has a list of attributes used by the tag, however they said that it's not *evaluated*.